# Is there anyone who using Ajax load more wordpress plugin?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Can anyone Tell me how to add custom J-query in Ajax load more repeater Template in word-press?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin that can help you. Configure as according to the plugin documentation given.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/